How to build a given csproj only on specified platform
I'm working on a project that generates bindings for a cross platform c library. The bindings are automatically generated for a specific platform. In my solution I have 3 projects.

Project.Windows.csproj
Project.Linux.csproj
Project.MacOs.csproj

How can I prevent the Linux and MacOs csproj from building when on windows.

You can set which projects need to be built in the solution properties.

Not sure why I did not think of that before :), If you post it as answer I will accept it

You can set which projects need to be built at any place below:

The solution properties window > Configuration Properties
The build menu > Configuration Manager...

